# Android KTX: how to override Kotlin added property extension

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-extension, android-ktx

I am trying to override View.setRotation() method in Kotlin.

Since AndroidKTX already provided property extension "rotation", caller's can simply call

`viewObject.rotation = 90.0f`

to rotate the view.

However, I want to add some additional operation when user change the rotation, like

```
override fun setRotation(newRotation: Float) {
    if (rotation == newRotation)
        return
    rotation = newRotation
    doSomethingElse()
}
```

This will crash because of StackOverflow error.

So, I have to add some additional code to achieve the goal:

```
    private var _rotation: Float = 0.0f
    override fun setRotation(newRotation: Float) {
        if (_rotation == newRotation) {
            return
        }
        _rotation = newRotation
        updateRotationInternally()
    }

    private fun updateRotationInternally() {
        super.setRotation(_rotation)
        doSomethingElse()
    }
```

This works, but I wonder if there is some other more elegant way of doing this, like "override the property extension setter"?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that there is no way to do that. Kotlin extension functions map to Java `static` methods, and you cannot override a `static` method.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, so I have to stick to the trick now. But is there any more elegant trick to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree with one aspect of your implementation: your `return` shortcut. You are assuming that calling `setRotation()` with the existing rotation value has no effect. It would not surprise me if that is true in the official Google version of `View`, but for all we know, that is not a safe assumption on some Oppo device running their modified version of Android 8.0. Try not to assume the behavior of stuff that you didn't write. If you want to skip `doSomethingElse()` when the old and new rotations are equal, that's fine.

I am guessing that your `setRotation()` functions are in some subclass of `View`. If so, and taking my above complaint into account, here's the simplest that I could come up with:

```
class Bar : View() {
  override fun setRotation(f: Float) {
    val needSomething = getRotation() != f

    super.setRotation(f)

    if (needSomething) doSomethingElse()
  }

  fun doSomethingElse() {
    println("got here!")
  }
}
```

My overall test code was done in [a Kotlin scratchpad](https://klassbook.commonsware.com/scratchPad.html) (outside of Android), so I tested with a fake `View` implementation and fake `rotation` extension property:

```
open class View {
  private var r: Float = 0.0f

  open fun setRotation(f: Float) {
    r = f
  }

  fun getRotation() = r
}

var View.rotation: Float
  get() = getRotation()
  set(value) = setRotation(value)

class Bar : View() {
  override fun setRotation(f: Float) {
    val needSomething = getRotation() != f

    super.setRotation(f)

    if (needSomething) doSomethingElse()
  }

  fun doSomethingElse() {
    println("got here!")
  }
}

fun main() {
  val bar = Bar()

  bar.rotation = 15.0f
  bar.rotation = 15.0f
}
```

If you run this in that scratchpad, you will see `got here` printed on the console once, showing that while we successfully updated the extension property twice, we skipped `getSomethingElse()` on the second call, as the old and new rotation were the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Use super.getRotation() really can help to reduce the complexity of the trick. I think you have a typo in the sample code, should be: "!= f" instead of "== f", right?

Comment: @Robin: Yeah, I think you are correct, so I have updated the answer. Sorry about that!

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare you are the real expert here! Would you mind have a look at another question regarding the difference of view transform and texture transform on TextureView? The link is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61137482/android-what-is-the-difference-of-textureviews-settransform-and-setscalex-y